# MVVM Indexed Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, parameters

I am using WPF MVVM architecture and my ViewModel has an ObservableCollection of object.  My Main ViewModel will look like below and it is binding to a list in main page, and it has a number of UserControls.  These UserControls are binding based on user selection from this List. How can I bind indexed data to UserControl relative to my Main ViewModel?

main ViewModel :-

```
   public ApplicationViewModel() {

    }

    private string selectedID;
    public string SelectedID
    {
        get { return selectedID; }
        set { selectedID = value;NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedID");  }
    }
   private ObservableCollection<RATA.Model.ApplicationModel> appViewModel;

    public ObservableCollection<RATA.Model.ApplicationModel> AppViewModel 
    {
        get { return appViewModel; }
        set { appViewModel = value;NotifyPropertyChange("AppViewModel"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi can u post the xaml code too it will be more useful .

Comment: Bind `SelectedItem` (instead of `SelectedId`) of the `ListBox` to a property on your viewmodel.  The user controls can then bind to that same property.

Comment: Do you have multiple selection on the listbox?